# Jubula test execution on remote Windows machine

Tags: jubula

I'm trying to get my Jubula tests to run on a remote AUT.  The AUT launches and can be controlled remotely, however when I actually run the tests, the steps don't execute.

If I install Jubula on the remote machine, and run the tests locally they run fine.

These are two Windows PC's with both firewalls off, so I'm sure it's not a firewall issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

there's a thread in the Jubula forum that might help with your question:
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/374796/

There might also be a good place to follow up with any other questions.

Hope that helps,
Alex